# html5 styles not working in IE8

Tags: css, html, jquery-masonry, modernizr

I am using modernizr & declaring display:block in css on elements but no styles are being applied!

The link is: http://www.complexd.co.uk/blog-intro/

Also jquery masonry is broken in IE - not sure if this is related. All my attempts to fix this have come to nothing, so would be grateful if someone could guide me in the right direction. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

download
http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Try this

`<!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
         <script src="/public/script/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->`

Change the src to whatever your path is

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I realise now I hadn't linked to modernizr properly, so html5shiv wasn't loading. Thanks for the heads up! Now I just need to figure out masonry issue...